# MySQL client without istio injection unable to connect to MySQL pod with istio injection

Tags: mysql, kubernetes-helm, istio

I have a K8s job (MySQL client) that waits until the MySQL pod is up, and connects to the MySQL pod and run some commands. However, as K8s job has to terminate, istio-injection label is set to false for the K8s job. Thus, the MySQL client pod (running as a job) is without istio-proxy, while the MySQL pod itself is run with istio-proxy. However, the MySQL client can't connect to MySQL pod. Removing the istio-proxy for both pods results in a success.

MySQL client tries to connect to the MySQL with internal host (mysql.NAMESPACE.svc.cluster.local)

Any solutions? MySQL image 5.7 (with latest Bitnami Helm Chart), kubernetes 1.19, istio 1.11.

Comment: Please explain step by step how did you set up your cluster. What do you have to use istio for? Where exactly is the problem? What is the expected result?

Comment: Perhaps mtls ? https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authentication/authn-policy/